# Union of two array of two different Objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nspredicate

I have two arrays of two different objects

**object 1:**

```
Class  partner {
    var pImage: String?
    var pTimeStamp: NSDate?
    var pTitle: String?
    var ID: String?
}
```

**object 2:**

```
Class  customer {
    var cImage: String?
    var cTimeStamp: NSDate?
    var cTitle: String?
    var ID: String?
    var isCustomer : Bool? 
}
```

I want to create an `array` (in a efficient way, of-course) out of these two `array` `objects` such that no **partner** and **customer** object with same **ID** (*cID,pID*) should repeat  within new `Array`.
**Basically union** of these two array based on IDs. Please do help.

**EDIT:** **these objects are stored in CoreData and at the time I do want above desired result I have already two array of these object**

Comment: Basically your two classes have almost the same properties, why don't use heritage  to do this?

Comment: @ReinierMelian ok if do have a base class, how that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The super-clever way would be to make Set do all the work for you. Make these objects adopt a common protocol with an ID property. Define equality for that protocol to mean having the same ID value. Now, if you don't care about order, coerce the arrays to Sets and union the sets. If you do care about order, you'll have to use NSOrderedSet instead. You can coerce back to Array after performing the union operation.

The alternative (the "dumb" way) is to cycle thru the arrays, building a dictionary whose key is the ID value. Like the set based on ID equality, this prevents the repetition you're trying to avoid. It's not inefficient because you're only cycling once thru each array, and lookup of the dictionary key is fast. When you've built the dictionary, convert back to an array. Again, however, you're going to lose the original array order unless you take additional measures.

(Both these answers, however, assume that you're willing to modify your objects so that they can even live in a common collection; as things stand, they can't, as they are two unrelated types.)

Comment: I do care about order I want customer object on top, any code snippet if you can share

Comment: You might have an easier time with this if you can rethink your objects a little...

Comment: yeah right I can restructure these object, but at this stage of product 'no' I cant.

Comment: Okay, well, I stand by my answer. The problem is that you are comparing apples with oranges; you can't have an array of Customer-or-Partner because they are two different types. If you're not willing to be flexible about that, it's hard to see what your question even means.

Comment: you're right matt, I have to change something in Data models(since these two classes are almost same) to make these two class either apples or oranges, I take on this later and for now I used some workaround. Marking this ans as accepted. Thank you.