# Multidimensional array of two different object types

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, class, xaml

I am using WPF to make a small physics engine using XAML and C#.

I want to draw rectangles onto the form and apply basic physics movement to them based on mouse input. In the program, there is a Shape class that holds the properties such as gravity value, mouse velocity and mass.

I need to apply these properties values onto the rectangle drawings, so I have created objects from the Shape class to call those properties. However, Im going to have multiple rectangles so I need a method to ID the rectangles so I can apply these gravity/velocity/mass values to each separate rectangle. I have looked for ways to do this, [Union of two array of two different Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332660/union-of-two-array-of-two-different-objects), except I am not sure this is what I am looking for.

Below is the class that contains the physics values (gravity, velocity, mass)

```
namespace Shapes
{
    public class Shapee
    {
        int _count;
        Physics_Engine.MainWindow _parent;

        public Shapee(int clickcount, Physics_Engine.MainWindow parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            _count = clickcount;
        }

        public double Mass { get; set; }
        public double Velocity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my main class, I have created an array of objects from this class and also draw the rectangles.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double boxvalue;
    public const int MAXSHAPES = 20;

    Shapee[,] shapes = new Shapee[MAXSHAPES, MAXSHAPES];

    public int addshapeclickcount = 0;

    //Start
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        addshapeclickcount++;
        Debug.WriteLine(addshapeclickcount);

        if (addshapeclickcount < 20 && addshapeclickcount != 20)
        {
            //Draw rectangle
            var rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle()
            {
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Width = 20,
                Height = 20
            };
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 2);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, 6);
            Draw.Children.Add(rect);

            //Create shape object
            var shape = new Shapee(addshapeclickcount, this);
            shapes[addshapeclickcount] = shape; //Create new shape every button click
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("     Max Shapes Reached");
        }
    }
}
```

How would I be able to link these these two objects in an array so that I can assign the Shape mass and velocity values to the coordinate value of each rectangle object?

Comment: You would need to simplify your example, _and_ make it complete (see [mcve]), to present your question in a manner appropriate for Stack Overflow. As it is, your question is way too broad...there are too many different ways to interpret your concern, never mind to answer it. That said, it appears you're doing it "all wrong". Your entire physics simulation should be independent of the UI, so that all of the interactions can be done just with your user-defined objects. Then you should include properties in your user-defined objects that describe the visual aspect, and bind those to XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that this line is correct?

```
shapes[addshapeclickcount] =shape; //Create new shape every button click
```

I think that you can use a dictionary to link the objects (to maintain clean you Shappe class):

```
Dictionary<Shapee, System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle> links = new Dictionary<Shapee, System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle>();
```

And After every creation of this objects you can linked by:

```
links.Add(shape, rect);
```